# Book or a story about a group of people who had become immortal, and traced it back to a wagon train they had all been on

Tags: story-identification, books, immortality

I remember reading a story or book when I was younger, back in the 1970s I believe, about a group of people who had become immortal, and they traced the beginning of their immortality back to a wagon train they had all traveled with, and some substance they had all been exposed to on the trip.

Can't remember the name of the story or the author, but would love to find it and read it again.

Comment: Was their immortality treated as a blessing or a curse?  Were they trying to recreate the way they became immortal or negate it?  Did they know immediately that they'd become immortal or did it take a while (years) to figure out?  Was it simple not-dying immortality, agelessness, or complete invulnerability/regeneration?

Answer (score 30):

Could this be the short novel, ***[Tuck Everlasting](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/84981.Tuck_Everlasting)*** (1975), by Natalie Babbitt?

There are two film versions of the novel, from [1981](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081664/) and [2002](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283084/). The plot involves a family of settlers who stumble upon the Fountain of Youth during the 19th century.

This expository excerpt is from [the novel's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuck_Everlasting):

> The Tucks explain that, 87 years ago, they had passed through the wood while looking for land to farm. They drank from the spring. After twenty years, the Tucks realized they were not aging. Miles's wife left him, taking their son and daughter. Forced to leave their farm, the Tucks returned in the direction of Treegap. After seeing that the clearing around the spring had not changed in twenty years, the Tucks realized that the spring had made them immortal.

[image: Front cover of "Tuck Everlasting" (1975) by Natalie Babbitt.]

Comment: You beat me to it!  If I recall correctly, the clue that settled it for them was that their horse drank from the spring (and became immortal) but their cat didn't (and lived a natural life).